# Show that $Ann(T,v)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{F}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is the vector space of all polynomials of arbitrary degree

> Let $T: V \to V$ and $v \in V$. The **order ideal** of $v$ with respect to $T$, denoted $Ann(T,v)$ is thet set of all polynomials such that $f(T)(v) = 0$.

> $f(T)(v) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k a_iT^i(v)$

We now want to show that $Ann(T,v)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{F}[x]$, In other words, we must show that if $h(x) \in Ann(T,v)$ and $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$, then $h(x)f(x) \in Ann(T,v)$.

(Since $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is commutative, we need not concern ourselves with "left" versus "right" ideals).

---

*Proof Start.*

We start by letting $h(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \in Ann(T,v)$ and let $f(x) =  \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^m b_ix^i \in \mathbb{F}[x]$. Now, since $h(x) \in Ann(T,v)$,

$$h(T)(v) = a_1T(v) + a_2T^2(v) + \dots + a_nT^n(v) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_iT^i(v)  = 0$$

---

At this point, I'm inclined to either say something about $T$ being a linear transformation (but this is problematic since $T$ and $T^i$ aren't related in any intuitive way). If not that, there must be something about polynomials I can say here, perhaps about divisibility?

Let me know where to go from this point. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The key fact is that $T^i$ and $T^j$ commute (even though arbitrary linear maps need not). Then commutativity of polynomials solves it since $f(T)h(T) (v) = h(T)f(T) (v)$.

Comment: You want to show $\left( h(T) f(T) \right)(v) = 0$.  It might help that $\left( \sum_i h(T) b_i T^i \right)(v) = \cdots = \sum_i b_i T^i(v) h(T)(v) = \sum_i 0 = 0 \text{.}$  The "$\cdots"$ is not one step and those steps need some explanation.